# Magento Overwrite blocks

Tags: magento

I need to overwrite Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review. I tried following code. But it did not work for me.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <modulename>
                <class>Abc_Mymodulename_Block</class>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_review>Abc_Modulename_Block_Onepage_Review</onepage_review>
                </rewrite>
            </modulename>
        </blocks>
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for not working this please.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite needs to be in a different place:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <abc_blockprefix>
               <class>Abc_Modulename_Block</class>
            </abc_blockprefix>
            <!-- here is where rewrite starts -->
            <checkout> <!-- class prefix -->
                <rewrite>  <!-- do rewrite -->
                    <onepage_review>Abc_Modulename_Block_Onepage_Review</onepage_review><!-- on this class-->
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
```